# Malformed SQL result in Spark SQL: columns mismatched showed up in the same row

Tags: sql, date, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a Spark SQL like below in the purpose to
list all names in `MY_TABLE` where `name`'s `count` changed from either `<10` to `>-10` or from `<100` to `>=100` in between today and the day before.

```
SELECT DISTINCT d2.name as NAME, d2.region_id as REGION_ID, d2.count as COUNT,
   date_format(to_timestamp(d2.VERSION_TIME, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") as VERSION_TIME
FROM MY_TABLE AS d1
RIGHT JOIN MY_TABLE AS d2
   ON d1.VERSION_TIME = d2.VERSION_TIME - interval 1 day    
   AND d1.name = d2.name
   AND d1.region_id = d2.region_id
   AND d2.region_id = ${region_id}
WHERE (coalesce(d1.count, 0) < 10 AND d2.count >= 10
       OR coalesce(d1.count, 0) < 100 AND d2.count >= 100
      )
   AND d1.VERSION_TIME BETWEEN cast("${date}" as timestamp) - INTERVAL 8 DAYS AND cast("${date}" as timestamp) - INTERVAL 1 DAYS
   AND d2.VERSION_TIME BETWEEN cast("${date}" as timestamp) - INTERVAL 7 DAYS AND cast("${date}" as timestamp)
   AND d1.region_id = d2.region_id
   AND d2.region_id = ${region_id}
;
```

Somehow, my result became:

```
NAME    REGION_ID    COUNT    VERSION_TIME
abc      5            3       2019-08-28T00:00:00.000Z
def      5            123     2019-08-28T00:00:00.000Z
ghi      5            12      2019-08-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

It looks good at first glance, but the reality is that `abc` doesn't exist in REGION_ID 5 at all, neither do `def` and `ghi`.

I'm not sure why this is happening, anyone could share any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please explain the logic you are trying to simplement.

Comment: Good call! just did that, thanks! @GordonLinoff

Comment: What does the data look like?  One row per name per day?  Or multiple rows per day?

Comment: Side note -- you have redundant criteria.  For example, there is no need to have `d1.name = d2.name` both in the join criteria and in the `where` clause.

Comment: I don't know anything about spark.  But I don't think what you've described (`abc` doesn't exist in `region_id` 5) is possible from the query -- presuming you mean "there are no rows in my_table where name = 'abc' and region_id = 5".

Comment: where do you see that in `where` clause? @avery_larry

Comment: it's also against my understanding of SQL, but this is what I'm faced with now @avery_larry

Comment: it's one row per name per day @GordonLinoff

Comment: @FisherCoder  Sorry, meant `d1.region_id = d2.region_id` in both where and join criteria.

Comment: You're sure that `select * from my_table where name = 'abc' and region_id = 5` returns no results?  We might need some actual sample data from my_table.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  If I follow the logic correctly:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LAG(count) OVER (PARTITION BY name, region_id ORDER BY version_time) as prev_count
      FROM MY_TABLE t
     ) t
WHERE count BETWEEN prev_count - 9 AND prev_count + 9 OR
      count > prev_count + 100 OR
      count < prev_count - 100;
```

Comment: thanks! how about these two conditions: `AND d1.VERSION_TIME BETWEEN cast("${date}" as timestamp) - INTERVAL 8 DAYS AND cast("${date}" as timestamp) - INTERVAL 1 DAYS
   AND d2.VERSION_TIME BETWEEN cast("${date}" as timestamp) - INTERVAL 7 DAYS AND cast("${date}" as timestamp)`

Comment: If you want to add date filters, add them to the subquery.